# What's stopping other rock layers from creating a karst-like landscape?

Tags: science-based, geography, chemistry, geology, minerals

### Context

I've reread a part of a book about geochemistry and it reminded me that just about any element can dissolve in water if the pH is right. Later an examples of aluminium or iron dissolving en masse in various regions and getting deposited was given, like the Amazon transporting few millions of tons of iron to the Atlantic this way.

### Question

Whats stopping other types of rocks to form their karst-like landscapes and structures, here on Earth?

### My guess

Carbonate (and other calcium rich) rocks are widespread and conditions for their dissolution easy enough to achieve, that such formations made out of other rocks are seem much rarer in comparison.

Comment: I think you're talking about solutional limestone caves, aren't you? If not, please specify why that isn't the answer to your question.

Comment: @RobertRapplean because karst terrain also has its surface features, like karst ribs, grabens and bowls, ponors and poljas or even karst springs
Edit: Of course I want to know about underground features too, but I don't want to dismiss the surface ones

Comment: *"Just about any element can dissolve in water if the pH is right": Too bad that rocks are most usually formed of various minerals and not of uncombined elements. It doesn't matter whether aluminium dissolves in water or not, what matters is whether [alumina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) dissolves in water. (Spoiler: it does not.)